# sed for specific line which contains a string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file such as

```
READS2b=/path1/path2/data/a_ACTTGA_L002_R2.fastq.gz.1
READS2b=/path1/path2/data/a_ACTTGA_L004_R2.fastq.gz.1
READS2b=/path1/path2/data/a_ACTTGA_L004_R2.fastq.gz
```

and I would like to change `/path1/path2/data/` to  `/path4/path5/data/` only for line which contains `.fastq.gz.1`.

Here I should get:

```
READS2b=/path4/path5/data/a_ACTTGA_L002_R2.fastq.gz.1
READS2b=/path4/path5/data/a_ACTTGA_L004_R2.fastq.gz.1
READS2b=/path1/path2/data/a_ACTTGA_L004_R2.fastq.gz
```

I would use:

```
sed 's@/path1/path2/@path4/path5/@g' file.txt
```

but I do not know how to do it only for line with `.fastq.gz.1`

Comment: Check this one, it might be exactly what you need: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155331/sed-replace-a-character-in-a-matched-line-in-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sed '/\.fastq\.gz\.1$/s@/path1/path2/data/@path4/path5/data/@g' file.txt
```

See a [`sed` demo](https://ideone.com/OQ3CDm)

Here,

- `/\.fastq\.gz\.1$/` finds lines that end with `.fastq.gz.1`
- `s@/path1/path2/data@path4/path5/data/@g` only replaces `/path1/path2/data/` with `path4/path5/data/` on those lines.

Comment: Might this make a wrong substitution if `data` does not follow the first two paths?

Comment: @potong That is just the OP command, I just fixed the bit OP had troubles with. Updated to make sure there is `/data` in the input.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\.fastq\.gz\.1/s#/path1/path2\(/data/\)/path4/path5\1#' file
```

Focus on lines that contain `.fastq.gz.1` and substitute when patterns match.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, in case you are ok with `awk`. In `awk` solution I have come up with 2 variables named `currText` and `newText` which are self explantory by their name itself, one could place text in these variables and we could globally substitute currText value with newText in lines wherever lines have `.fastq.gz.1` in it.

```
awk -v currText="/path1/path2/data/" -v newText="/path4/path5/data/" '
/\.fastq\.gz\.1/{
  gsub(currText,newText)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk '/fastq.gz.1/ {gsub(/path1/,"path4") gsub(/path2/, "path5")}'1 file
READS2b=/path4/path5/data/a_ACTTGA_L002_R2.fastq.gz.1
READS2b=/path4/path5/data/a_ACTTGA_L004_R2.fastq.gz.1
READS2b=/path1/path2/data/a_ACTTGA_L004_R2.fastq.gz
```

this code:

- first the condition. Only these records: `/fastq.gz.1/`, not all.
- and second the action, in this case the substitutions with `gsub`.